# Why is SymPy's solver returning only one, trivial solution?

Tags: python-2.7, solver, sympy

I want to find all the real numbers that satisfy a particular equation. I have no trouble finding these values in *Mathematica* with

```
Solve[n*9^5 == 10^n-1, n]
```

which [gives both 0 and 5.51257](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bn%2a9%5E5%20==%2010%5En-1,%20n%5D&dataset=); but when I use SymPy's (0.7.3; Python 2.7.5) `solve`

```
n = sympy.symbols('n')
sympy.solve(n*9**5 - 10**n-1, n)
```

I seem to only get something that looks like 0, and not the second value, which is what I'm really seeking.

How can I get SymPy to produce the non-trivial solution I'm looking for? Is there a different function or package I should be using instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`solve` only gives symbolic solutions, so if it cannot find a closed form for a solution, it will not return it. If you only care about numeric solutions, you want in SymPy is `nsolve`, or you can use a more numerical oriented Python library. For example

```
sympy.nsolve(n*9**5 - 10**n-1, n, 5)
```

will give you the solution you are looking for.

---

The problem with using `solve` is that there are infinitely many solutions, each corresponding to a branch of the LambertW function. See [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bn%2a9%5E5+%3D%3D+10%5En-1%2C+n%5D&dataset=) for the full solution set. Unfortunately, [only the principal branch of LambertW is implemented in SymPy](https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=4006).

Until this is fixed, another way to fix the issue would be to manually evaluate the LambertW returned by `solve` on another branch, using `mpmath.lambertw`. The easiest way to do this is with `lambdify`:

```
s = sympy.solve(n*9**5 - 10**n-1, n)    
import sympy.mpmath
# Replace -1 with any integer. -1 gives the other real solution, the one you want
lambdify([], s, [{'LambertW': lambda x: sympy.mpmath.lambertw(x, -1)}, "mpmath"])()
```

This gives `[mpf('5.5125649309411875')]`.

The dictionary tells `lambdify` to evaluate the `LambertW` function using the `-1` branch, using mpmath. The `"mpmath"` tells it to use mpmath for any other functions that may be in the solution.

Comment: Don't know why it won't render that URL.

Comment: Apparently you don't have to use private APIs like I initially thought you did. See the edited solution in case you happened to read what I initially wrote.